# TinyMCE Stripping Out "controlsList" Attribute on HTML 5 Audio Tag

Tags: html, tinymce, 2sxc

In the TinyMCE editor I want to add a valid element attribute, the HTML5 audio and video attribute "controlList". It's an experimental attribute but supported in Chrome and we have a use for it. For example we want the following code to validate in TinyMCE:

```
<p>
    <audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload">
        <source src="some.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</p>
```

Right now 'controlsList="nodownload"' is not recognized and stripped out.

Tiny MCE's documentation shows that adding custom tags and attributes is possible using tinyMCE.init (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements). However I've looked at the source of 2sxc and I am not quite clear about the best way to do this in 2sxc's implementation of TinyMCE.

One possibility seems to be line 2045 of the file \dist\sxc-edit\sxc-edit.js (2sxc 9.14). There I added the tags & attribute to the existing validateAlso:

```
    validateAlso: '@[class]' // allow classes on all elements, 
            + ',i' // allow i elements (allows icon-font tags like <i class="fa fa-...">)
            + ",hr[sxc|guid]" // experimental: allow inline content-blocks
            + ",audio[controlsList]"
            + ",video[controlsList]"
```

However that didn't have the desired effect on my testing server and I don't love the idea of modifying source since my changes will be overwritten by the next patch I apply.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, tinyMCE is not configurable. Reason is that we're moving to a completely new implementation of the UI using Angular 7, and we don't want to introduce more features to migrate :)

If you really want to do this, I recommend you use the code for the input-type "string-wysiwyg" to create your own - let's call it "string-wysiswyg-withfeatures" and register it as an input-type (there are some blogs about that) - then configure your field to use that wysiwyg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer iJungleBoy.

Comment: @iJungleBoy can you please provide any reference for custom "string-wysiwyg", e.g. links to the blogs you have mentioned? I wasn't able to find any when googling. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can start here: https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/browser/edit-form/custom-fields.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around that allows custom attributes to be added to an HTML tag.  Note this solution works for our one-off needs with HTML5 audio/video tags but may not work for everyone.

First we added an id of "my-player" to our audio tag.

```
<audio id="my-player" controls="controls">
  <source src="some.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Then we added a script which inserts the desired attribute using DNN Page Settings > Advanced > SEO > Page Header Tags:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#my-player').attr("controlsList", "nodownload");
});
</script>
```

In our case this javascript attribute insertion had the desired effect.